# using exec() to run unix `at` command

Tags: php, linux, unix

I need to run unix `at` command using PHP. How is it possible to do it? `curl` is not an option for what I am doing. If I try to run it simply `exec('at')` it gives no response. Though, if I run it using ssh, it works fine. So I guess this is permissions/path problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you have some real `at` command line because only `at` is invalid syntax. Your command should include some arguments.

However maybe your problem is that `at` is not in `$PATH`. Try to run at with the full path which is typically `/usr/bin/at`. Check this with `whereis at`.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that "at" receives its script from stdin, so you'll want to open a pipe to the at command using popen(). Write your commands to that pipe and close it. The time that you want "at" to run the command should be part of the command line when you open the pipe.

```
<?php
$r = popen('/usr/bin/at noon');
fwrite($r,"ls -l");
pclose($r);
?>
```

Comment: Just one note, you have to use "mode" with `popen`, like this: `$r = popen('/usr/bin/at noon','r');`

Comment: @Ajax, good catch. Except the mode should be 'w' in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Run `cat /etc/passwd` to check whitch shell is using the apache user, if is `bin/false` you can **NOT** run 'at' from apache user.

I found a tricks for this issue by exporting shell over bin/bash before running the shell command, something like this:

> export SHELL=/bin/bash; echo "shell command" | at :time: :date:

and passing it as argument for the php exec() function.

In this way you'll be able to run your 'at' scheduling from apache.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in the file "/etc/at.deny". Scan through the file you will see a line "www-data" which is the user that apache2 is running (the last line in the file in my case). This denies user "www-data" to run the "at" command. Simply delete that line from /etc/at.deny. Then you can run "at" using "shell_exec".

Hope it helps.